# Direct sum and basis of a module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be an $R$-Module and $(M_i)_{i=1,...,n}$ submodules. We call the sum of the $M_i$ direct, if every element in the sum has a unique representation $m_1+...+m_n$ with $m_i\in M_i$.

Let now be $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}\subset M$

Is it true that if $$M=\sum_{i=1}^n Rx_i$$ and the sum is direct, we can conclude that $X$ is a basis of $M$? Clearly, the other direction holds.

Comment: No. Consider the Klein $4$-group.

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easier example? I don't know this group.

Comment: It's just $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only free modules have bases, but nonfree modules can be direct sums of cyclic submodules.

As an example consider, for $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and take $x_1=(1,0)$, $x_2=(0,1)$.

Comment: Or just $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for the sake of argument ;)

Comment: @JJR I wanted to avoid trivial direct sums, but of course your example is sound.

Comment: That helps thank you! One question arised: Is it true that a basis of an finitely generated free module is finite?

Comment: @user114179 Yes. However, for noncommutative rings the size of a basis for a finitely generated module is not necessarily invariant.